# Path relative to multi-project build file

Tags: gradle, multi-project

I have a project structure like this:

```
config/
foo/
    build.gradle
    settings.gradle
    bar/
        build.gradle
    baz/
        build.gradle
```

I want to add the `config` directory to the classpath in `foo/build.gradle` so that the subprojects `bar` and `baz` can access it. I've tried doing this in `foo/build.gradle`:

```
subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'
    dependencies {
        runtime files('../config')
    }
}
```

But that results in the following entry in the classpath:

```
/home/me/project/foo/config
```

When what I actually want is:

```
/home/me/project/config
```

I believe it's because `runtime files('../config')` is being evaluated in `foo/bar/build.gradle` instead of `foo/build.gradle`. So, how can I get the path to `foo/`? I could just use `runtime files('../../config')`, but it doesn't feel quite right.

Or maybe I'm going about this the wrong way and there's a better place to put the config files?

Comment: What lives in the config folder? Source files, binary dependencies (jars, wars etc)  or static resources?

Comment: @RaGe Resources that might change with deployment, like database connection parameters *etc*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to get to your current config folder location irrespective of which project/folder level you're at is:

```
"$rootDir/../config"
```